# Does NetEase's Pomelo use Udp or Tcp?

Tags: node.js, tcp, unity-game-engine, udp, pomelo

I recently decided to make a multiplayer FPS game using Nodejs (server) and Unity3D (client). I already did a POC with socket.io and deployed it on heroku for testing which failed miserably ( the packet delivery was too slow which created lag).
After digging around I found out that socket.io uses TCP which is not ideal for a face paced FPS game. Then I came across Pomelo and it seemed interesting.

But before I spend time on its POC, I need to know. 
Does Pomelo only use TCP or does it also support UDP?

Thanks :)

Comment: OK it turns out that when you run pomelo init, it asks which underlying connector you want to use and UDP is listed among them.
But now there is no client-side (Unity3D) implementation of PomeloUDP, it only works with socket and socket.io [https://github.com/NetEase/pomelo/wiki/Client-platform-supported]

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

For an FPS you will probably want to use UDP. I found this for Unity: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/open-source-udpkit-a-networking-library-for-net-mono-unity.215161/

As far as TCP goes, I think TCP is more generally used protocol for more data-centric requests, like chat or things that require packet integrity(UDP tolerates packet loss to lower latency).

Answer (score 0):

NetEase's Pomelo Don't support Tcp